# How can I make an Ext JS grid with a column of check boxes that toggle each row as editable?

Tags: extjs4.1

I am trying to create a grid with a column of check boxes that toggle whether or not each row is editable. As of yet, I have not found a way to make more than one row editable by any means. I like the idea of using the CheckboxModel for selection as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957837/checkboxmodel-makes-some-particular-fields-editable), but I could not get the edit part to work and I want to edit the entire row.

Answer (score 0):

The onl;y difference from that example is a type of editor. Replace

```
var editor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        });
```

with

```
var editor = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        });
```

Comment: What I really want is for the controls on multiple rows to be visible at the same time. The RowEditing plugin only allows for one row at a time.

Comment: have not seen that in the wild